# To Find Height and Width of Image in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, minimagick

I'm using carrierwave and mini_magick gem to find image resolution.

```
def image        
        pic = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.picture.path)
        pic.width; pic.height;           
        return pic         
end
```

But I'm getting this error

`Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory)` ):